# Find the values of N such that for n>N |$a_n$-3|< $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I have the sequence $a_n$ = $\frac{9n^2 - 1}{3n^2 -2}$

I need to find the values of N such that for n>N |$a_n$-3|< $\epsilon$

So far I have the following

|$\frac{9n^2 - 1}{3n^2 -2}$ - 3| < $\epsilon$ for n>N

|$\frac{9n^2 - 1 - 9n^2 + 6}{3n^2 -2}$| < $\epsilon$ for n>N

|$\frac{5}{3n^2 -2}$| < $\epsilon$ for n>N

Can I take away the modulus signs as the 3.n^2 will always mean the -2 has no affect and the answer will remain positive

Also any help finishing the question would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n$ sufficiently large and positive, you will of course have $3n^2-2>0$. It follows that
$$
\epsilon>\left|\frac{5}{3n^2-2}\right|=\frac{5}{3n^2-2}\iff 3n^2-2>(5/\epsilon)\iff n>\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}((5/\epsilon)+2)}.
$$
It remains to make sure that $3n^2-2$ is actually positive. Any nonnegative integer $n$ actually will do so it's enough that $n$ is greater than $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}((5/\epsilon)+2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to find the limit. In that case, you can increase $N$ as much as you like. So, instead of trying to find an integer such that
$$\left\lvert\frac{5}{3n^2-2}\right\rvert < \epsilon$$
it is enough (and easier) to find an integer such that
$$\left\lvert\frac{5}{3n^2-2}\right\rvert < \left\lvert\frac{5}{3n^2-n^2}\right\rvert < \epsilon$$
where the first inequality is true as long as $n>1$. Thus, find an integer $n_\epsilon$ that satisfies the last inequality and take $N=\max\{n_\epsilon, 1\}$